# Is the immersion $i: H^1(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^4(\Omega)$ continuous in $1D$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I know that in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the immersion $$i: H^1(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^4(\Omega) $$ is continuous. Is it also true when $\Omega = (0,1)$,i.e. an open interval in one dimension?

Comment: For a bounded interval, it's a composition of two continuous inclusions $H^1\hookrightarrow L^\infty\hookrightarrow L^4$ (the first one being Sobolev embedding, and the second one Holder's inequality).

Comment: Could you be more explicit on the first inclusion? I can't figure out how you used Sobolev embedding's thm @Jose27

Comment: I say Sobolev embedding, but in 1D it's really the fundamental theorem of calculus: $$ u(x)= u(y)+\int_y^x u'(t)\, dt ,$$ valid for any $x,y$ in your domain $\Omega$. the integral in this expression can be bound, using Cauchy-Schwarz, by $diam(\Omega)^{1/2}\| u'\|_2$, then integrate the resulting inequality with respect to $y$ to get $$\| u\|_\infty \leq |\Omega|^{-1}\| u\|_1 + diam(\Omega)^{1/2} \| u'\|_2$$.

Comment: thanks. If you merge your comments, I can accept this as an answer!